# jquery this context

Tags: javascript, jquery

let's say I have two divs like this:

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <textarea class="info_box" attribute="first" rows="4" cols="40">Enter text here...</textarea>
    <button class="submit_btn">Click me!</button>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
    <textarea class="info_box" attribute="second" rows="4" cols="40">Enter text here...</textarea>
    <button class="submit_btn">Click me!</button>
</div>
```

I want to be able to get the textarea within each div when I click on my button 'submit_btn'. I tried something like this:

```
$('body').delegate('.myDiv .submit_btn', 'click', function(){
    var myTextarea = $('.info_box', this);
});
```

But that returns undefined

Any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$('body').delegate('.myDiv .submit_btn', 'click', function(){
    var myTextarea = $(this).closest('myDiv').find('.info_box');
});
```

Another solution :

```
$('body').delegate('.myDiv .submit_btn', 'click', function(){
    var myTextarea = $(this).siblings('.info_box');
});
```

Note that if you have a version of jQuery more recent than 1.7, it's better to use `on` instead of `delegate`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `this` is scoped to `.myDiv .submit_btn` and inside of there, the textarea does not exist. Perhaps try `this.parentNode` as the scope.

Answer (score 0):

so if you want to get the textarea, why not simply do this

```
$('.submit_btn').on('click',function(){
     var myTextarea= $(this).siblings(".info_box");
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wef44/)