# jQuery this context to point to the element in context

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a situation using BS3 modal events and my app functionality is wrapped in object with exposed methods (reveal module pattern). I have event received from BS and I what my $this to point to the Event object instead of the App object. 
I tried [jquery this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604049/jquery-this-context) with the jQuery proxy, which seems to be the best thing, but for some reason the things didn't worked for me

```
var globalAppDef = (function() {

function modalFilters() {
    $('#filtersMore')
    .on('show.bs.modal', (event) => {
        const sourceElement = $(event.relatedTarget);
        $(sourceElement.data().filters).removeClass('hidden');
    })
    /*
     * Transfer the proper @this of the event outside the {globalAppDef} Object
     */
    .on('hidden.bs.modal', $.proxy((event) => {
        $(this).find(".form-list-items-1").addClass('hidden');
        $(this).find(".form-list-items-1").addClass('hidden');
    }, this));
}

return modalFilters: modalFilters

}
});

var globalApp = new globalAppDef();
globalApp.initialize();
$(document).ready(function () {globalApp.modalFilters()});
```

What I what to achieve is on the second hidden.bs.modal $this to point to my Modal, which is $('#filtersMore') element.

Answer (score 0):

actually it it was the Arrow function the reason for that this stayed in the Object context. 
That way worked:

```
.on('hidden.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (event) {
        $(this).find(".form-list-items-1, .form-list-items-2").addClass('hidden');
    }, $('#filtersMore')));
```